# iOS lock event?

Tags: iphone, ios, events, locking

Is there a way to run an action when the iPhone gets locked?

I simply want to run a little bit of code when the iPhone gets locked by the user. I'm looking for a solution that works without a jailbreaked iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888507/267892

> May be you need to implement following methods in `AppDelegate`:
>
> Tells the delegate that the application is now in the background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

> Tells the delegate that the application has become active.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

> Tells the delegate that the application is about to become inactive.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

See [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on these.

Comment: Does that even work if the app is running in background? (sorry, i´m new to iOs-programming and i´m often not sure whar i´ve to google.. )

Comment: Unfortunately not, the only thing you can do is get notified whenever the user closes your app.

Comment: hm, so there is no possibility to run code when the iphone gets locked and the app is in background? Thanks for your fast answer.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, no. Background-tasks and notifications are limited to what is mentioned in the "App States and Multitasking" in Apple's iOS App Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

especially `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable:`
and `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable:`