# It is possible to record video in iPhone device screen off mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, video-recording

Am working in iPhone device camera based iOS application. I have one requirement to record **video from our application even the device screen is off or in locked**. I don't have iPhone, iPod and iPad. And also i don't know it is possible to record video in these conditions. Cound you please give me any idea on this? Looking forward your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible as the BackgroundTasks doesnt contain Video as a Task. Following tasks are capable of having background operations
1: Audio
2: VOIP
3: Location Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. There's no other way to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So that we can't do this in iOS application. But, some apps are providing the video recording in black screen mode. How they are doing that? Could you please help me? Ex: SpyCam : Stealth Video Camera. Thanks.

Comment: SpyCam is not on App Store. It works only on Jail Break phones.

Comment: there is : https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/spycam-stealth-video-camera/id891534531?mt=8  and if you want to do that by yourself , u need little ios developpement knwolegde by monitoring the event of spring board on lock!/unlock event and check of the current apps if is is camera then do ur magic cancel the event and send black screen here u can start http://stackoverflow.com/a/14271705/2971944

Answer (score 0):

In some countries it's against the law to even take picture without sound effect, such as Japan for example. No wonder Apple don't allow to shoot pictures from locked screen.