# Reload iPhone application after locking the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to restart my iPhone application, if it was in process and the device was locked and unlocked again. How can it be done?

Comment: maybe duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone

Comment: What do you mean by "restart"? Why do you need to do it?

Comment: @Wain, I need to start the app from the very beginning, from the view controller, that was first shown in the app

Comment: Is that a login screen or something? You should aim to remember where the user was and take them back there. If you need to re-authorize then show that as a modal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the methods that are called when the app goes in the background and when its brought back in the foreground. They are defined in your appdelegate.m file:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

You can write code in these methods to "suspend" and "restart" your application when the user locks and then unlocks the phone respectively.

Hope that gives your pointers.