# How to determine number of locks and unlocks of iPhone programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, device, unlock

is it possible to determine how many times my iPhone has been locked and unlocked programmatically when app is foreground and background as well. Code snippet will help a lot...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect screen lock/unlock events on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get this information from your App.

You can only know when your app goes to foreground/background via your App Delegate, but not what the user does outside of your App.

Comment: There are apps like breakfree & instant with this feature running in appstore.