# Monitor how long an iPhone has been unlocked for

Tags: ios, swift, timer

Is there a way to monitor how long an iPhone has been unlocked for during a day using Swift?

Comment: You can try to calculate it youself using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone) and translating it to Swift, but it may lead to a rejection from the App Store.

Comment: Do you want to check how long it has been unlocked as total or unlocked since the user has used your application?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to monitor how long a phone has been unlocked for during a day

No, because this would require that your app actually be running at unlock time, and of course you can't possibly guarantee that.