# iOS: Can I detect if the device screen is on/off?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, screen

How can I check if the screen is on or off in iOS? I'd like to know if the screen is currently on, even my app is in the background. I'd like to have an event listener on this. thanks.

Comment: What if I detect screen lock / unlock event instead? Can i do that? (Instead of screen on off)

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 3** you can do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Observer UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,UIApplicationDidEnterBackground
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationDidBecomeActive(notification:)),
                name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive,
                object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(MyViewController.applicationDidEnterBackground(notification:)),
                name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground,
                object: nil)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
  // here my app did become active
}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
  // here my app did enter background
}
```

You can find more details in the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1).

---

Details from the actual sources:

```
extension NSNotification.Name {
    // These notifications are sent out after the equivalent delegate message is called
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public static let UIApplicationDidEnterBackground: NSNotification.Name
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public static let UIApplicationWillEnterForeground: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationDidBecomeActive: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationWillResignActive: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationWillTerminate: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange: NSNotification.Name
    public static let UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientation: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSNumber with new orientation
    public static let UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientation: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSNumber with old orientation
    // userInfo dictionary key for status bar orientation
    public static let UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrame: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSValue with new frame
    public static let UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrame: NSNotification.Name // userInfo contains NSValue with old frame
    // userInfo dictionary key for status bar frame
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let UIApplicationBackgroundRefreshStatusDidChange: NSNotification.Name
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public static let UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable: NSNotification.Name
    @available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public static let UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable: NSNotification.Name   
    // Key in options dict passed to application:[will | did]FinishLaunchingWithOptions and info for UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification    
    // This notification is posted after the user takes a screenshot (for example by pressing both the home and lock screen buttons)
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public static let UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot: NSNotification.Name
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems this can only check the state of my app. What I need to do is to check the screen status that is on or off

Comment: Any advise on this?

Comment: There is no public API to do what do you want: warning, if you use some private API your app could be judge as not valid from Apple review, you must use the official API guidelines

Comment: I'd plan to use this for some research, not plan to do a public launch, so grateful if you would help me on some kind of solution, even it is private API.

Comment: If i use private API, can the app deploy as an AdHoc one and install it to my testers' devices?

Comment: No, I'm sorry but also test-flight versions should be passed from app review since test-flight became a part of itunes connect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

It seems that I have no way to do what I want. Actually, I just want to keep track on how long the user has the screen on..... :(

Comment: What if I detect screen lock / unlock event instead? Can i do that? (Instead of screen on off)

Comment: UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable: this appears when device is locked but warning this notification is not sent unless the device has a passcode setup. There are no notification about locked/unlocked  device

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for getting state of screen in ios.

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                displayStatusChanged, // callback
                                CFSTR("com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

Comment: Sorry that I am not very understand this part of code. Would you explain more? I am new to this. I am going to write this in swift. Any advise?

Comment: I have also tried the code that got error on "CFSTR" and CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately

Comment: All you need to know is that this isn't the answer.  "com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus" could change and everything will break.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5 only this worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711257/7505029