# Send local notifications ONLY when phone is in use?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am working on an iOS app that sends the user a scheduled local notification every minute. However, I want to do this only when the phone is in use. As of now, it sends the notifications even when the phone is locked. Is there any way I can code for this in Swift?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think so that its possible in ios environment.

Comment: that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171495/ios-can-i-detect-if-the-device-screen-is-on-off

Comment: You need to observe `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` notifications.  Turn them off when you enter the background and turn them on again when you become active.