# How to hide multitasking snapshot in iOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot, snapshot, multitasking

I am developing a security application. I need to disable the multitasking snapshot from being taken by iOS. I have made a fix for this by adding a black screen over my application window, when application resigns active mode. This logic seems to work fine when I press home button. But when I lock the screen, the logic is not effective, since the snapshot is already taken before control comes to `applicationWillResignActive` method. I have verified this by downloading the container folder from devices tab. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone Maybe this can help you?

Comment: Thanks @Hoa. The above link had a clue how to catch device lock notifications. I consumed it to fix my issue.