# React Native: How to detect device lock/unlock event?

Tags: react-native, lockscreen

**Concept:**

My application needs to record user activities on phone. Activities contain Foreground, Background, Kill, Lock and Unlock.

**What I did:**

I am able to record application's Foreground, Background and Kill states using [AppState library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html).

**Requirement:**

I need to perform actions on device Lock/Unlock states. Unfortunately I am unable to listen device lock and unlock event in above library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that day I couldn't find any way to **detect Lock/Unlock** event in React native.

**Solution:**

1. We've **created sample modules** in **Android and iOS** separate (**Native code** to get **Lock/Unlock** events)
2. Using **Android studio / XCode** we've **exported** as **React native modules**
3. **Imported** these modules in **React native**

It works fine for us.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Do you have these modules in github or some place public?

Comment: Yes. But not as of now. Can provide in weekend.

Comment: Are they available now? @HirenPatel

Comment: @HirenPatel can you please  provide sample for this?

Comment: @HirenPatel Would love to see that as well

Comment: @HirenPatel would you be able to provide the sample repo? Thanks.

Comment: Hey I have faced same problem can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is pretty much a sandbox within your device. Listening to unlock states is not tied to anything within your app.

Your next best hope is to do something like this, but I would not recommend it as it most likely violates private API's (This is iOS only): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14271705/1363779