# React native detect whether phone screen is off

Tags: react-native

I'm making an app which wants the user to keep the app open and not using other apps (to help them focuses on works), but allows them to turn the phone screen off. I used AppState API to detect if the app running in the background but it also triggered when the screen turned off.
So I need a way to know if the screen is on or off. I tried googling around but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735832/react-native-how-to-detect-device-lock-unlock-event