# React Native detect screen lock/unlock when app is running in the back ground

Tags: android, react-native

**Problem**: I need a way to measure if the screen is locked/unlocked while my app is running in the background.

**What I have tried**: Using React Native's [App State](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate), I can measure if the App is active, but there is no differentiation between the App being in the background or the screen is locked.

I have found this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735832/react-native-how-to-detect-device-lock-unlock-event), however since there has been no solution given I have opened a new question.

I'm looking for a solution for Android.

Answer (score 1):

When your application is in the background, the process running React Native is paused. You cannot manage your event from inside your application.

The only solution is to use [headless js](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android).