# React native Webview blocked after Screen Lock (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I'm working on an ios react native app, I'm using webview to get data periodically, and use it in my app, 
but when I lock my iphone device, the webview stop sending data to react native.

```js
onWebViewLoad() {
   setInterval(function(){
      this.refs.webview.injectJavaScript('window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(window.getData());');
   }, 10000);
}

handleMessage(event) {
   // receive data
   //doSomething(event.nativeEvent.data)
}
```

```html
<WebView
  source={{ uri: this.state.myPage }}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  startInLoadingState={true}
  onLoad={this.onWebViewLoad}
  ref="webview"
  onMessage={this.handleMessage}
  />
```

Note: code is working fine when app in foreground or background, but when I open the app and lock the screen the webview stops sending data.

Is there a way to make the webview send data after screen lock.

Comment: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/how-can-i-detect-screen-lock-unlock-events-on-the-iphone/14271705#14271705) you can detect Lock or Unlock status of iPhone. I think you should call your method for both states.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be only the WebView which is blocked. I think also the timers are blocked when screen is locked.

Closely correlated with the subject called [wake-lock](https://www.w3.org/TR/wake-lock-use-cases/) for which - as mentioned in the article - sometimes playing hidden video methodology is used to avoid the CPU sleep.

Using the similar workaround, you can try the method in this [github post](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/issues/9#issuecomment-291562476) to use the timers when screen is locked. (*)

Quoted from [github post](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer/issues/9#issuecomment-291562476) of the method:

> ...this seems to work for me:
>
> 1. Start background timer in componentWillMount()
> 2. Play a silent sound during the time when you want the background timer to be active. This can be something like react-native-sound file which is playing on repeat
> 3. Add the following to your `info.plist` file:
>
> ```
> <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
> <array>
>  <string>audio</string>
> </array>
> ```
>
> Note that you should still abide by the apple terms of service, and only do the above if you are in one of their accepted use-cases for background playing.

(*) Please note, this requires using the [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) and [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) packages. Its logic is very similar to the above [wake-lock](https://www.w3.org/TR/wake-lock-use-cases/) article. And also it is better to think carefully if what you are doing complies with IOS policy or not.

Comment: I'm already playing a video in background, and that problem still exist, I think the problem is related to the execution of javascript inside the webview it's get blocked when sceen lock like in safari browser

Comment: I know a silly question but let me ask, can the phone be in vibration mode? (Once my audio failed because of it in iOS)

Comment: are you calling state changes after some callback or whatnot?
I had a similar problem when I used setState after calling some other function, which made the app hang sometimes, and didn't have any feedback like a crash or something.